# Where are the user guides for Mirth Connect?

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

Where are the user guides for Mirth Connect?

Google searches point to [an older forum post](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=217379) and relatively old links to version 3.0.1. The current release is 3.6.1 and is several years newer than those links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a frequent question in the [Mirth Connect Slack](https://mirthconnect.herokuapp.com/) channel.

The most recent user guides are available from the [Mirth Connect Downloads page](https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/NextGen-Connect-Integration-Engine-Downloads) under the "User Guide" tab. NextGen has now published them on a persistent, live link at https://docs.nextgen.com/

Release notes are available from the [Mirth Connect releases page on GitHub](https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/releases).

Starting with Mirth Connect 4.0 there is a link in the Mirth Connect Client that points to http://downloads.mirthcorp.com/connect-user-guide/latest/mirth-connect-user-guide.pdf

Comment: There is a tab "user guide" on the Mirth Connect Downloads page that can be easily overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

The user guide of the last version (v3.10) is:

https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-310-user-guide.pdf

Comment: I've also found that changing the URL fragment that denotes the version from `310` to another minor version, such as `38`, can currently give you that version's PDF too. Therefore, version `3.8` can be found at: 

https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-38-user-guide.pdf

and `3.9` can be found at: 

https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-39-user-guide.pdf

Hope it helps anyone looking for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

NextGen has just released the user guide as a web page here: https://docs.nextgen.com/bundle/Mirth_User_Guide_41/page/connect/connect/topics/c_Introduction_mirth_connect_ug.html

I think it's much easier to search through and is more organized than the PDF.